# requireJS an entire folder

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is it possible to "require" an entire folder using requireJS.

For example, I have a behaviors folder with a ton of behavior js files. I'd really like to be able to simply use require(['behaviors/*'], function() {...}); to load everything in that folder rather than having to keep that list up to date. Once compressed and optimized I'd have all those files lump together, but for development it's easier to work with them individually.

Comment: which environment are you running requireJS in? if client-side, the answer is a definite no.

Comment: it's late in the game, but I wrote a library that can do exactly this,  added an answer below - https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs-metagen

Answer (score 24, accepted):

javascript in browser has no filesystem access and so it can't scan a directory for files. If you are building your app in a scripting language like php or ruby you could write a script that scans the directory and adds the file names to the require() call.

Comment: this seems unnecessary. i love requirejs and this is something requirejs should handle. you should be able to require a directory and all it's subcontents.

Comment: @AlexMills but how would you expect a browser to know the names of all the script files on a web server? requirejs is a client-side language. Your frustration is in the limitation of client-server architecture, not require.

Comment: you should be able to make a build that lists all the files in a dir and requirejs uses a list of paths to require the files, just make that a part of a build system, but requirejs has to handle that gracefully on the front-end too. I wrote something that does this and it works well if youre interested I can link you to it.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if I can recommend this approach anymore. I think the more explicit way to do this is by manually "requiring"/"exporting" the functionality you need. The exception I think is if you have a "namespace" of files that you want exported see below "Babel and ES6 Module Import Declarations (export-namespace-from) or see below "Babel and ES6 Module Import Declarations.

These solutions also assume that you have a meaningful file structure - where file names become part of that "require" `*` definition.

However, if you still need to do this there are a few existing tools and methods that might provide the behavior that you're looking for.

---

**Possible Solutions**

**Babel and ES6 Module Import Declarations (plugin-export-namespace-from)**

1. Have a setup that is [ES6 compliant](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation).
2. You need to update your `.babelrc` file to include [babel-plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from).
3. Use export namespace plugin by writing syntax like the following:

**common/index.js**

```
export * from './common/a'; // export const a = false;
export * from './common/b'; // export const b = true;
```

**main.js**

```
import { a, b } from './common';

console.log(a); // false
console.log(b); // true
```

**Babel and ES6 Module Import Declarations (plugin-wildcard)**

1. Have a setup that is [ES6 compliant](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation).
2. You need to update your `.babelrc` file to include [babel-plugin-wildcard](https://github.com/vihanb/babel-plugin-wildcard).
3. Use wildcard namespace plugin by writing syntax like the following:

**main.js**

```
import { a, b } from './common/*'; // imports './common/a.js' and './common/b.js'

console.log(a); // false
console.log(b); // true
```

**RequireJS (Now Outdated)**

1. Download and install [`require-wild`](https://npmjs.org/package/require-wild) `npm install require-wild`
2. Configure the declaration as follows

```js
    grunt.initConfig({
        requireWild: {
            app: {
                // Input files to look for wildcards (require|define)
                src: ["./**/*.js"], 

                // Output file contains generated namespace modules
                dest: "./namespaces.js", 

                // Load your require config file used to find baseUrl - optional
                options: { requireConfigFile: "./main.js" }
            }
        }
    }); 
    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("require-wild");
    
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['requireWild']);
```

3. Then run the grunt task. Your file will be generated. Modify your setup  to load `namespaces.js`

`require(['namespaces'], function () { ... });`

4. This now allows modules under `src` to use dependencies glob pattern matching.

`require(['behaviors/**/*'], function (behaviors) { }`

Comment: this package has been unpublished :( darn it

Comment: @DmitryMatveev https://github.com/dpk-it/require-wild seems to look like the original code but I no longer recommend/own it. This question was a bit outdated to begin with. I'd recommend using one of the babel plugins I mentioned above. Sorry I removed the `require-wild` pkg - I also realize that providing a non-requirejs solution is kindof frustrating but I think its the right approach - Hopefully you found a solution to the problem you were running into.

Comment: It also looks like @alexander-mills has an alternative for `require-wild` too https://github.com/ORESoftware/requirejs-metagen but I haven't looked into it too heavily.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I'd like to share my solution:

For this solution you need JQuery

1) Create a **bash script** that will **list all the js files** in
    "MyDirectory/", and **save it to "directoryContents.txt"**:

```
#!/bin/bash
  #Find all the files in that directory...
  for file in $( find MyDirectory/ -type f -name "*.js" )
        do
          fileClean=${file%.js} #Must remove .js from the end!
          echo -n "$fileClean " >> MyDirectory/directoryContents.txt
        done
```

- File will look like this:

> MyDirectory/FirstJavascriptFile MyDirectory/SecondJavascriptFile
>   MyDirectory/ThirdJavascriptFile

- Problem with my script! Puts an extra " " at the end, that messes things up! Make sure to **remove the excess space** at the end of **directoryContents.txt**

2) Then in your Client side JS code:

- do a "GET" request to retrieve the text file
- For each entry (split by the space), 'require' that file:

.

```
$.get( "MyDirectory/directoryContents.txt", {}, function( data ) {
    var allJsFilesInFolder = data.split(" ");
    for(var a=0; a<allJsFilesInFolder.length; a++)
    {
        require([allJsFilesInFolder[a]], function(jsConfig) 
        {
            //Done loading this one file
        });
    }
}, "text");
```

I was having a problem with this code not finishing before my other code, so Here's my extended answer:

```
define([''], function() {

return {

    createTestMenu: function() 
    {
        this.loadAllJSFiles(function(){
            //Here ALL those files you need are loaded!
        });
    },

    loadAllJSFiles: function(callback)
    {   
        $.get( "MyDirectory/directoryContents.txt", {}, function( data ) {
            var allJsFilesInFolder = data.split(" ");
            var currentFileNum = 0;
            for(var a=0; a<allJsFilesInFolder.length; a++)
            {
                require([allJsFilesInFolder[a]], function(jsConfig) 
                {
                    currentFileNum++;
                    //If it's the last file that needs to be loaded, run the callback.
                    if (currentFileNum==allJsFilesInFolder.length)
                    {
                        console.log("Done loading all configuration files.");
                        if (typeof callback != "undefined"){callback();}
                    }
                });
            }
        }, "text");
    }
}
});
```

What I ended up doing was everytime my Node server boots, it will run the bash script, populating directoryContents.txt. Then My client side just reads directoryContents.txt for the list of files, and requires each in that list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried something very similiar but instead generated a 'deps.json' file with all the modules mapped out. Minifying this however wasn't exactly ideal..

Comment: i am going to try something like this tomorrow and see how it goes, thanks

Comment: i think i can devise a simpler solution, but in my head neither your solution nor mine will probably work with r.js the optimizer. would you mind telling me if your solution works with r.js and how? thx!

Comment: i double checked. in order for a solution like this to work with r.js, the optimizer, you need to literally state the filepaths of the files you want to require in either the define or require function dependency array. this is because the r.js optimizer does static analysis and cant see variable name values because those are only available at runtime of course.

Comment: so in other words you need to print out the filepaths from the text file into  the define([]) array, the the optimizer can include those. you could also write the filepaths to the include in the optimizer build config file but that wouldnt work for development.

Comment: I finished a library that does exactly this. https://github.com/ORESoftware/requirejs-metagen enjoy! btw, you don't need bash to list out directories, it's much easier just to do it in a "modern" (scripting) programming language, IMO

Answer (score 1):

**There isn't really a way to do this conceptually on the fly (that I know of).**

There's a few work arounds though:

Use `grunt` and `concat` and then just require that behemoth...I know, kinda sucky.

What I think is a better solution... use a require hierarchy like so:

```
require('/js/controllers/init', function(ctrls){
    ctrls(app, globals);
});

// /js/controllers/init.js
define('js/controllers/index', 'js/controllers/posts', function(index, posts){
    return function protagonist(app, globals){
        var indexModule = index(app, globals);
        var indexModule = posts(app, globals);

        return app || someModule;
    };
});

// /js/controllers/index.js
define('js/controllers/index', 'js/controllers/posts', function(index, posts){
    return function protagonist(app, globals){
        function method1(){}
        function method2(){}

        return {
           m1: method1,
           m2: method2
        };
    };
});
```

Note that "`protagonist`" `function`. That allows you to initialize modules before their use, so now you can pass in a '`sandbox`' -- in this case `app` and `globals`.

Realistically, you wouldn't have `/js/controllers/index.js`... It should probably be something like `/js/controllers/index/main.js` or `/js/controllers/index/init.js` so that there is a directory adjacent to (sibling of) `/js/controllers/init.js` called "index". This will make your modules scalable to a given interface -- you can simply swap modules out and keep your interface the same.

Hope this helps! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library to solve this problem. Eventually someone else came along and improved my library, here it is:

https://github.com/smartprocure/directory-metagen

You can use my lib with Gulp or whatever - it generates metadata for your project and RequireJS can use that metadata to require the desired files from the filesystem.

Using this lib will produce a RequireJS module that looks something like this:

```
define(
    [
        "text!app/templates/dashboardTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/fluxCartTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/footerTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/getAllTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/headerTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/homeTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/indexTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/jobsTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/loginTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/overviewTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/pictureTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/portalTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/registeredUsersTemplate.ejs",
        "text!app/templates/userProfileTemplate.ejs"
    ],
    function(){

        return {

            "templates/dashboardTemplate.ejs": arguments[0],
            "templates/fluxCartTemplate.ejs": arguments[1],
            "templates/footerTemplate.ejs": arguments[2],
            "templates/getAllTemplate.ejs": arguments[3],
            "templates/headerTemplate.ejs": arguments[4],
            "templates/homeTemplate.ejs": arguments[5],
            "templates/indexTemplate.ejs": arguments[6],
            "templates/jobsTemplate.ejs": arguments[7],
            "templates/loginTemplate.ejs": arguments[8],
            "templates/overviewTemplate.ejs": arguments[9],
            "templates/pictureTemplate.ejs": arguments[10],
            "templates/portalTemplate.ejs": arguments[11],
            "templates/registeredUsersTemplate.ejs": arguments[12],
            "templates/userProfileTemplate.ejs": arguments[13]
        }
    });
```

You can then require modules in your front-end like so:

```
var footerView = require("app/js/jsx/standardViews/footerView");
```

however, as you can see this is too verbose, so the magic way is like so:

name the dependency above as allViews!

now you can do:

```
var allViews = require('allViews');
var footerView = allViews['standardViews/footerView'];
```

There are two advantages to requiring directories whole:

(1) in production, with the r.js optimizer, you can point to one dependency (module A) and it can then easily trace all of A's dependencies that represent a entire directory

(2) in development, you can require whole directories up front and then use synchronous syntax to require dependencies because you know they have already been loaded

enjoy "RequireJS-Metagen"

https://github.com/smartprocure/directory-metagen

https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs-metagen

https://github.com/ORESoftware/requirejs-metagen