# Node.js and Require.js include an entire directory

Tags: node.js, requirejs

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892978/requirejs-an-entire-folder) but it applies to the browser. I was wondering if I could require every file in a directory when using require.js in node.

Is there a short cut or would I have to manually iterate all files in a folder and require them one by one?

Comment: A quick google search for "npm require all files in a directory" brought up [require-all](https://npmjs.org/package/require-all) and [node-require-directory](https://npmjs.org/package/node-require-directory).  Or are you looking for an npm-free solution, or do other modules not work with require.js?

Comment: I am using require.js and want to use it to manage dependencies.

Comment: @AranMulholland It is true that the answers to the question you link to are meant to solve the problem for code running *in the browser*, but by the same stroke they solve the problem for code running *in Node*. So why are they not acceptable to you?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to place an index.js file in the directory, which in turn requires all the files in the directory that are related to your project. Then you can require your directory, and require.js will look up all the entries in the index.js file.