# Is there a way to reduce the number of references declared in jasmine unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using jasmine to test my angular code.

On the top of each file with specs I am having a bunch of references.

For example these are the references I need in one of my tests:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/angular.js" /> 
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/angular-route.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/angular-animate.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/App/app.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/App/Common/Directives/ngProgress.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/App/Modules/Naviagation/navigationApp.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/App/Common/Directives/angularBootstrapNavTree.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/App/Common/Factories/commonFactory.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/App/Modules/Naviagation/NavigationBar/navigationFactory.js" />
```

Is there another way to declare all those references. For example, something like:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/* (this does not work)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html)? It will allows you to do that (include all files in a defined directory) directly in the config file.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Chutzpah test runner. As far as i know, Karma is not  integrated well with team foundation build server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chutzpah does let you do that in a few different ways.

One way is to have a reference path to a folder (omit that *):

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts" />
```

That will get all files (recursively) in that folder.

If you want more control you can use the references setting in a [chutzpah.json](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chutzpah%20File%20References&referringTitle=Documentation) file

```
{
    "References": [
        { "Path": "../../../../../Project/Scripts", "Include": "*.js", "Exclude": "*Resource*" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Karma will work better, you can do stuff like `scripts/**/*.js` to include every js file under scripts

or you can use requirejs and list them like this:

```
require(["angular.js", "angular-route.js"]
```

or a more hackicsh approach like:

[requireJS an entire folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892978/requirejs-an-entire-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the trick using web essentials. It allows selecting all the javascript references(files) I need, through different location of the project, and group them in one bundle. And I need to reference only the bundle in my spec like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../Project/Scripts/navigationControllerReferencesBundle.js" />
```