# load a folder with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm working with requireJS clientside, and want to "require" an entire folder using requireJS. 
Basically what I want has been asked already here:

[requireJS an entire folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892978/requirejs-an-entire-folder)

I'm aware, that there is no fileaccess, so my solution is, that the Webserver (Apache), when queried a folder, returns its content/index in some JSON format.
This is accomplished with mod_rewrite and a php-script.

suppose the path is "path/to/folder/"

This works perfectly fine, when done "manually" with an XMLHttpRequest (I use jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path/to/folder/",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(d) {console.log(JSON.stringify(d));}
})
```

however it does not work with requireJS:

```
require(["text!path/to/folder/"], function (d) {
    console.log(d);
});
```

in the latter case `d` is the empty string.

Comment: Have you checked with the browser's debugger network tab, what is the URL requested by RequireJS when requiring `"text!path/to/folder/"`? Is it the correct one?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, thank you!!
the requested adress is not the correct one, but "?[object%20Object]" is appended.
The reason is this requirejs config setting:

    urlArgs: { 'bust': Date.now().toString() }

I use it to prevent requirejs caching. this solution seems very annoying at times. Is there any better way to disable that caching?

.. Also I'm not sure yet how to edit this question accordingly.

Comment: Oh, you are using it wrong! `urlArgs` takes a *string*, not an object! ([check it out](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs)) The correct usage would be: `urlArgs: 'bust='+Date.now().toString()`, or exactly as in the docs: `"bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime()`